# SQL - Update Query - access the value of a field I set in another field I am setting

Tags: sql, hash, sql-server-2012, passwords

I am tasked with implementing password hashing and I have to hash all the current user records by writing a SQL script to do it. So far, I have been able to create unique salts (from a different question I also asked) but I'm having trouble trying to actually hash them.

my code is:

```
UPDATE 
    user

SET 
    pass_salt = left(NEWID(), 13)
    ,user_pwd = convert(varchar(100), HASHBYTES('SHA1', user.user_pwd + user.pass_salt), 2)

WHERE
    security_user_id = 98
```

My issue is I'm not really sure how or if I can access the pass_salt field while setting user_pwd. Currently, it just returns null.

Notes: I am using SQL Server 2012. I am using a 'where' clause to only change one record for testing purposes.

All help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a CTE:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT u.*, left(NEWID(), 13) as new_pass_salt
      FROM user u
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET pass_sale = new_pass_salt,
        user_pwd = convert(varchar(100), HASHBYTES('SHA1', user_pwd + new_pass_salt), 2)
    WHERE security_user_id = 98;
```

In general, in an `update`, the values on the left of the `=` come from the "new" record and the values on the right from the "old" record.